# Query by complex Object field

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Consider the document with complex object field:

```java
@Getter  @Setter
@Document
class A{
   @Id
    private String id;

 @Field(
        type = FieldType.Object,
        includeInParent = true
    )
    private B b;
}

@Getter  @Setter
class B{
String field1;
C c;
}

@Getter  @Setter
class C{
String field1;
}

public interface ARepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<A, String> {
    Optional<A> findByB(B b);
}
```

When I execute the `aRepo.findByB(someB)`, the built query  doesn't extract `B` fields, but contains the result of  `someB.toString()` as filter for field `b`.

I have JPA background and expect similar behavior . If this is not supported, what is the recommended approach for these kind of queries ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is the equivalent of [Query By Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) (QBE), this is not yet supported in Spring-Data-ES.

Searching on an class object should be dependend on your mapping, if your mapping is determined by application (@Field on fields with @Mapping and [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html) set to false), and by looking at public `interface ElasticsearchRepository<...>` - you will have to manually build your query using [QueryBuilder](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-query-builders.html) (Elastic abstraction) or [Criteria](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/Criteria.html) (Spring-Data-ES abstraction) and then [customizing your repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository).

If your mapping is not determined by application (already set on elastic before), you would have to know it [field types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html) (is it a 'text', 'keyword', etc), then there might be different behavior expect for each type (match query, term query, filter, etc) - and this will also have to be custom-implemented with QueryBuilder or Criteria.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if there is open issue to support QBE query in Spring data ES?

Comment: don't think so,